# How to resolve TLS version issue with MongoDB cluster in java Spring Boot web project?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

I am building a Spring Boot web application that uses MongoDB as a data store. I am communicating directly to the live cluster (not a local cluster) using a MongoDB URI. I am using Java 11 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.5).

On application startup, my application is unable to communicate to MongoDB cluster due to what looks like a TLS/SSL error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:551) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:433) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:273) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:257) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na
```

According to sources on MongoDB's [driver website](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/tutorials/ssl/), they explain that this is a known issue with Java 11. I believe the issue to be [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236039) filed with OpenJDK, where it notes an issue with the implementation of SSL connections for TLS 1.3. This provides me with two options:

1. Upgrade to a version of Java that has fixed this.
2. Set the `jdk.tls.client.protocols` system property value to `TLSv1.2`.

I have been able to verify that this issue does *not* resolve when upgrading to Java 15; the error remains *identical*. I double checked that I was actually using Java 15 before cleaning and rerunning the application with `mvn spring-boot:run`.

That leaves me with the second option, which brings me to my question:

#### How do I correctly set `jdk.tls.client.protocols` system property when building with Maven?

I've tried running the application with `mvn spring-boot:run -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` but that still gives the same error as before.

I've provided my `pom.xml` below; I have **zero** files/code pertaining to MongoDB auto setup in the project, which you can examine in it's entirety [here](https://github.com/ucsb-cs156-f20/proj-mapache-search/tree/2b4eab2b0d72d27dfbe710adeab79e3771e68567).

For clarification, I am engaging the `localhost` build profile.

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>edu.ucsb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapache-search</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>Mapache Search</name>
    <description>Mapache Search (CMPSC 156 class project)</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jpa, crud repository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- add mongodb repositories -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.codebox/javabean-tester -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.codebox</groupId>
            <artifactId>javabean-tester</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>javascript</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.12.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.14.3</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>ci</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/javascript/build" />
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Fix the error
        Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules
        but the packages defined in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/
        are in the unnamed module. -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Make jar file executable -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- full package name of class with the main you want to run -->
                            <mainClass>edu.ucsb.mapache.DemoApplication</mainClass>

                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Test case coverage report -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- (28) <profiles/> -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>localhost</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/config/localhost</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>.</directory>
                                            <include>secrets-localhost.properties</include>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <environment-properties />
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.TEST_PROPERTIES</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <environment-properties>${env.TEST_PROPERTIES}</environment-properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>heroku</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.HEROKU_PROPERTIES</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/config/heroku</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>

            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <environment-properties>${env.HEROKU_PROPERTIES}</environment-properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I have also included the output of `mvn dependency:tree` below:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< edu.ucsb:mapache-search >-----------------------
[INFO] Building Mapache Search 0.1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ mapache-search ---
[INFO] edu.ucsb:mapache-search:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20190722:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- net.codebox:javabean-tester:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:runtime
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.022 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-10T12:28:18-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you pass that variable correctly (for Spring Boot 2.X.X):

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2"`